# SCCM Software Center WMI query missing applications

Tags: sccm, wmi

I am using the below query to check the Software center available and installed applications. But some of the apps are missing in the query but available in Software Center. Is there any other query required to get missing applications.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace  ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -Class CCM_Application -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object InstallState, Fullname
```

Also i can see Microsoft Office and some licensed software also missing in the query.

Comment: are you sure the ones missing are using the application deployment model and not the package+program one?

Comment: Hi Sybedoor. I can see these packages when i open the Software center console. But WMI query is missing these applications.

Comment: Yeah but what I mean is in the sccm console you can create your deployable software using the application model or the package model and in software center you would not see a (big) difference but in wmi you would. You would see the legacy programs under CCM_Program instead. Another thing that comes to mind is that ClientSDK is somehow user dependent somehow even for software that is per machine (I don't fully understand how this works because some stuff is visible for everyone but it is maybe worth trying with a different user for you just to be sure)

Comment: Thanks Sybedoor and i was able to get missing apps from CCM_Program. Much appreciated and sorry for the late reply

Comment: No problem, great that you found them